# Binding sub-menus in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, binding, menu

Is there any way to bind sub-menus in tkinter?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

main_menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu = main_menu)

test_menu = Menu(main_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Test Menu" , menu = test_menu)

test_menu.add_command(label = "Sub-Menu 1")
test_menu.add_command(label = "Sub-Menu 2")

mainloop()
```

Here, I want to bind `Sub-Menu 1` and `Sub-Menu 2` with some event(eg - `<Enter>`),  just like we bind any other widget.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: Enter key is binded by default to menu item: it calls the 'command' option of add_command

Comment: Yes, but how can I use other bindings in menu items?

Comment: Menu items are not real widgets. I do not exclude it can be done at tcl level, but i don't know.